# Side mirror fell off, what adhesive should I use to re-attach it

Tags: wing-mirrors

The plastic mirror surface came free from the side mirror housing.

Is there a special type of adhesive that should be used for this?  Or with a good cleaning would most adhesives work?

Comment: Plastic, as in coated acrylic?

Comment: @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing Yeah plastic with a mirrored backside.

Comment: Any good adhesive formulated for plastic will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gorilla glue or Loctite should work well. Loctite is used on airliners.

http://www.loctite-consumer.co.uk/en/did-you-know/about-loctite/airplanes.html

// Information below from the website link above. \\

> Did you know about Loctite and airplanes?
>
> From commercial airlines to space shuttles, Loctite’s adhesives are industry leaders in aerospace manufacturing. These toughened, engineering glues are used to join vital parts of the aircraft together such as engine components, wing flaps, landing gear doors and internal fittings.
>
> Loctite is trusted to provide secure and impact resistant bonding in an industry where there can be no margin for error. Metal, plastic, wood, glass and rubber are attached with exceptional strength, providing resistance to corrosion, chemicals, thermal shock and extreme temperatures.

Here are some steps from eHow to ensure a side mirror is installed well.

http://www.ehow.com/how_6798177_glue-side-mirror.html

> How to Glue a Side View Mirror
>
> By Brenda Priddy
>
> A side view mirror is a necessary piece of equipment on any car.
>
> The side view mirror allows the driver to see behind and to the sides of the car, which prevents accidents while changing lanes.
>
> Side view mirrors must be present and complete to pass a car inspection. When a side view mirror becomes damaged, it is important to replace the mirror right away to prevent accidents.
>
> Replacing a side view mirror is a simple project that anyone can do at home.
>
> Things You'll Need
>   Non-latex construction silicone adhesive
>   Replacement mirror
>   Large, flat head screwdriver
>   Heat gun
>   Bucket
>   Work gloves
>   Masking tape
>   Safety goggles
>   Extension cord (optional)
>   Shop rags
>
> Remove the old mirror from the frame. Wear work gloves and safety goggles, when removing the old mirror, for safety. Place a large bucket under the mirror to catch any broken glass pieces.
>
> Connect a heat gun to a nearby electrical outlet. Use an extension cord, if necessary, to reach the outlet and mirror. Heat the surface of the mirror with the heat gun until the surface of the mirror is hot to the touch.
>
> Scrape away the mirror pieces with a large, flat head screwdriver. Try to remove one piece at a time. If the mirror is still in one or two solid pieces, then hit the mirror with the back of the screwdriver to break it into smaller pieces for easier removal. Scrape the pieces out one by one until they are all removed. If necessary, re-heat the surface of the mirror if the adhesive hardens again before all of the pieces were removed.
>
> Clean away any remaining glue by wiping the surface of the mirror with a wet rag. Do not use chemical products on the mirror housing or the adhesive may not stick when you glue the new mirror. Wipe down both sides of the mirror as well.
>
> Apply five beads of silicone to the back of the mirror. Place one bead on each corner and one in the middle. Use a bead about 3/8 of an inch in diameter and apply it ½ inch from each mirror edge.
>
> Press the mirror firmly into the mirror housing for about 30 seconds; however, do not apply too much pressure or the mirror may break again. Wrap the entire mirror housing and mirror with masking tape to hold the mirror in place so it does not fall out before the glue dries. Leave the tape over the mirror for 24 hours before removing.
>
> References
>   Auto Glass: Car Mirror Repair
>   Nichols Tip: Side-View Mirror Glass Removal

// End of eHow article and all credit goes to the eHow author mentioned above \\

Comment: I happened to have a tube of loctite laying around from putting some tac strips down on concrete a couple weeks ago, thats what I ended up using

Answer (score 5):

I would use something from the Sikaflex range:

For example, Sikaflex 221
http://www.elise-shop.com/sikaflex221-adhesivesealant-p-506.html

This is used for Lotus Elise repairs and bonding various bodywork. It has some flex but is very strong.

That said, most mirror glasses attach via clips into the housing, so make sure either a clip hasn't broken and requires fixing or it just needs pushing back on.

Answer (score 0):

I just sticky taped the frame and taped the edges of the mirror. It's in and I don't have a male friend. It will do for now